# Efecto de botón con dos colores CSS

Tags: css, javafx, botón

Tengo una ventana que lleva unos botones de opción, pero no encuentro la forma de darle este estilo al botón:

[image: Botón dividido por dos colores]

En CSS se hace así (Ver comentario//):

```css
.button {
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: "Montserrat", "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0.8em 1.4em;
 padding-right: 4.7em;
 background: @button-colour;
 border: none;
 color: white;
 transition: 0.2s;
 &:before,
 &:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-top: inherit;
  padding-bottom: inherit;
  //ancho del rectangulo que contiene el icono
  width: 3.8em;
  content: "\00a0";
  font-family: "FontAwesome", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;

  transition: 0.2s;
  transform-origin: 50% 60%;
 }
 &:before {
  background: @button-tint;
 }
 &:hover {
  background: darken(@button-colour, 10%);
 }
 &:active,
 &:focus {
  background: darken(@button-colour, 30%);
  outline: none;
 }
}
```

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Quieres igualar la tonalidad de los azuls? osea quieres que sean iguales?

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema si ya tienes los estilos?

Comment: El problema es que ese estilo salió de una hoja de estilos para un sitio web, no se como aplicar ese CSS en JavaFX.

Comment: No es CSS sino Less (un preprocesador de CSS). Tienes que convertir ese código a CSS para poder usarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder usar ese código tienes que hacer algunas cosas. Lo primero, no es CSS sino [Less](http://lesscss.org/)(un prepocesador CSS) así que tienes que convertirlo en CSS pero antes tienes que darles un valor a las variables:

```
@button-colour: #009ED8;
@button-tint: #008EC2;
```

He usado los colores de tu ejemplo pero puedes poner lo que quieras, despues de eso pones el resto del código y lo conviertes a CSS con alguna herramienta para esa tarea, hay montones, pero lo más sencillo es buscar un conversor online, por ejemplo: http://lesscss.org/less-preview/. Pegas hay el código en Less y te devuelve el CSS:

```
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.8em 1.4em;
  padding-right: 4.7em;
  background: #009ED8;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.button:before,
.button:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-top: inherit;
  padding-bottom: inherit;
  width: 3.8em;
  content: "\00a0";
  font-family: "FontAwesome", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.2s;
  transform-origin: 50% 60%;
}
.button:before {
  background: #008EC2;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #0079a5;
}
.button:active,
.button:focus {
  background: #002e3f;
  outline: none;
}
```

Para el icono de la lupa necesitas la tipografia [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) que aparece en los estilos y cambiar el código de la propiedad `content` ya que la lupa usa el código `/f002` y no `/00a0` que es un espacio en blanco.

Para usar Font Awesome puedes descargarlo o usar un CDN, pongo la versión 4 porque la actual (la versión 5) es un poco diferente.

Y ya solo queda darle a tu botón la clase `.button` y ajustar si lo necesitas el ancho del recuadro del icono o cualquier otro estilo:

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.8em 1.4em;
  padding-right: 4.7em;
  background: #009ED8;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.button:before,
.button:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-top: inherit;
  padding-bottom: inherit;
  width: 3em;
  content: "\f002";
  font-family: "FontAwesome", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.2s;
  transform-origin: 50% 60%;
}
.button:before {
  background: #008EC2;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #0079a5;
}
.button:active,
.button:focus {
  background: #002e3f;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="button">Search</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tengo una propuesta no se si te guste

Codigo CSS

```
.button{
    width:100px;
    display:flex;
    background:;
    }
.button #search{
    background: #B2ffff ;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:65%;
}
.button #search:hover{
    background: #A9FFFF
}
.button #lupa{
    background-color:#A9FFFF;
    width:35%;
}
.button #lupa img{
    width: 20px;
}
```

Html

```
    <div class="button">
        <a href="#" id="search">Search</a>
        <a href="#" id="lupa"><img src="lupa.png"></a>
    </div>
```

Se que no es un button pero sirve como tal si usas javascript en el button solo le añades el onclick y creo que resuelve... y te ahorras mucho codigo. Al CSS le falta algo de estilo ya queda a tu criterio y necesidades, yo tengo un boton como el que deseas y me funciona asi a la perfección. Espero te sirva amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es mi propuesta:
En el HTML necesitas un formulario y además del boton necesitas un input type text. El idea central es que estoy haciendo en formulario `display:flex;`, Espero que sea lo que necesitas.

```css
*{
  background: #603035;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing : border-box;
}

#buscar {
  margin: 1em auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}
#buscar form {
  height: 40px;
  max-width: 30rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;

}
#buscar form input {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 0 1 90%;
  align-items:center;
  border: none;
  background: #009ed7;
}
#buscar form input::placeholder {
  color: white;
  font-size:1rem;
  padding:1em;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#buscar form button {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1 0 50px;
  background: #008ec2;
  padding:0 1em;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: none;

}
```

```html
<div id="buscar">
  <form>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="buscar algo">
  <button>lo que fuera</button>  
  </form>
</div>
```